# "Basing" versus "based"

Tags: word-choice

I wrote the following question (referred to Italian), and I have been told it was not correct to use **basing** instead of **based**. (The person who told me this is an American English native speaker.)

> When is the past participle declined **basing** on the gender?

Why should I have used **based**, and not **basing**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> We base the declension of a past participle on the gender [of the noun it modifies].

(Of course as you know in English we don’t decline participles on any basis at all; so I assume we’re speaking of Italian or German or Latin or some other Indo-European tongue which has not yet dispensed with the declension of adjectives.)

This may be rephrased as

> We decline a past participle, **basing** the declension on the gender.

**Basing** here is the *present* or *active participle*; it modifies the Agent of the verb *base*, the one who performs the action, namely us.

Now recast the original proposition into the passive voice, as it is expressed in your question:

> Declension of the past participle **is based** on gender.

You cannot use the active participle **basing** here because you have deleted the Agent of that verb.

What you **can** use is the *passive participle*, **based**. In fact, you're already using it in the passive construction. This participle modifies the Patient of the action *base*, the one who receives or suffers the action, namely *declension*.

And if you now return *declension* to its ‘basic’ (forgive me) verbal form, as you do in your question, the action it denotes is still modified by the passive participle, not the active participle:

> The past participle is declined **based** on the gender.

Comment: But I think a judge could reasonably say *"Taking into account your past history, bail is refused"*. Which could (just about) be inverted to *"Bail is refused, taking into account your past history"*. It might not be the most elegant English around, but people (okay, maybe not so many well-educated judges! :) do use such forms. You're certainly right it doesn't pass muster in OP's exact context, but related usages do occur without necessarily raising eyebrows.

Comment: @FumbleFingers A judge could say it reasonably, but not grammatically: it's your classic dangling participle. Such things do not happen in Higher Courts, where magistrates have very highly educated clerks whose job it is to catch such innocent errors and correct them in the printed versions.

Comment: Yes, I agree there *is* a grammatical principle involved here - but the mere fact that we have the term "dangling participle" is evidence that it actually occurs often enough to actually have a name. My example probably wasn't the best, but there are certainly cases where it's barely noticed (if at all) by most people in casual contexts. I only really mentioned it as a possible reason why OP might have come across similar constructions. Obviously on some level *some* of us don't find it that "strange", even if we all agree awful in OP's exact context.

Answer (score 1):

A present participle, such as *basing* is generally used in one of three ways

1. to function as an adjective (e.g. I hear a **barking** dog)
2. to function as a noun (e.g. It was the dog's **barking** that led me to his hiding place)
3. combined with a form of the verb **to be** to function as a verb (e.g. The dog **is barking** at the mailman.  The cats **are fighting** in the alley.)

A past participle, such as *based* is generally used in one of these ways

1. The present perfect tense (e.g. I feel sick because I **haven't eaten**.)
2. The past perfect tense (e.g. I felt sick because I **hadn't eaten.**)
3. The future perfect tense (e.g. I **will have eaten** by the time you get home.)
4. The conditional perfect tense (e.g. If I had stepped onto the ice, I **would have fallen.**)
5. As an adjective (e.g. The **broken** vase doesn't hold water.)
6. The passive voice (e.g. The mailman **was bitten** by a dog.)

Now, let's apply this to your example, "When is the past participle declined based on the gender?"  First, for simplicity, I'll change the question to a statement.  "The past participle is declined based on the gender of the noun."  "The past participle **is declined**" is an example of the passive voice, but I think this will be more clear if we change the sentence so that it only uses one example of the passive voice, instead of two, so let's re-word it.  "The declension of the past participle **is based** on the gender of the noun."  Now, with this slight re-wording, I think that it becomes more clear that you are using a passive form of "base" and should therefore use based instead of basing.

Comment: When the *-ing* form functions as a noun, it is usually described as a **gerund** rather than a **present participle**.